# Dreamweaver Preview Browser different from Actual Webpage HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver, liquid-layout

I have created a webpage with multiple fluid divisions. In the website browser they are lined up in horizontal a row as they should be. When the page is actually uploaded to the site, they are vertical, appearing one underneath another.

Here is the following CSS sheet used:

```
@charset "utf-8";
@import url("Ubuntu_L/stylesheet.css");

/* Simple fluid media
   Note: Fluid media requires that you remove the media's height and width attributes from the HTML
   http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluid-images/ 
*/
img, object, embed, video {
    max-width: 100%;
}
/* IE 6 does not support max-width so default to width 100% */
.ie6 img {
    width:100%;
}

/*
    Dreamweaver Fluid Grid Properties
    ----------------------------------
    dw-num-cols-mobile:     5;
    dw-num-cols-tablet:     8;
    dw-num-cols-desktop:    10;
    dw-gutter-percentage:   25;

    Inspiration from "Responsive Web Design" by Ethan Marcotte 
    http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design

    and Golden Grid System by Joni Korpi
    http://goldengridsystem.com/
*/

/* Mobile Layout: 480px and below. */

.gridContainer {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 87.36%;
    padding-left: 1.82%;
    padding-right: 1.82%;
}
#LayoutDiv1 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv2 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv3 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv4 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv5 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv6 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv7 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv8 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv9 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

/* Tablet Layout: 481px to 768px. Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
.gridContainer {
    width: 90.675%;
    padding-left: 1.1625%;
    padding-right: 1.1625%;
}
#LayoutDiv1 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv2 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv3 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv4 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv5 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv6 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv7 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv8 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv9 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
}

/* Desktop Layout: 769px to a max of 1232px.  Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout and Tablet Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
.gridContainer {
    width: 88.2%;
    max-width: 1232px;
    padding-left: 0.9%;
    padding-right: 0.9%;
    margin: auto;
}
#LayoutDiv1 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 59.1836%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv2 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 18.3673%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv3 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2.0408%;
    width: 18.3673%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv4 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2.0408%;
    width: 18.3673%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv5 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2.0408%;
    width: 18.3673%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv6 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv7 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2.0408%;
    width: 18.3673%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv8 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 18.3673%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv9 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
}
```

I think this is a widespread problem. Any suggestions would be really appreciated!

Thankyou -

Andrew

EDITS:

Please see a snippet of the html below:

```
  <div id="LayoutDiv3">
<p><strong>Medical <br>
  </strong>&nbsp;Condition 1
  <input type="checkbox" name="Condition 1" value="Yes" />
  &nbsp;&nbsp; <br>
  Condition 2
  <input type="checkbox" name="Condition 2" value="Yes" />
  &nbsp;&nbsp; <br>
  Condition 3
  <input type="checkbox" name="Condition 3" value="Yes" />
  &nbsp;&nbsp; <br>
  Condition 4
  <input type="checkbox" name="Condition 4" value="Yes" /></p>
<br />
  <br />        
  </div>

  <div id="LayoutDiv4">
<p>  <strong>Dietary</strong>
<p>Type 1
  <input type="checkbox" name="Type1" value="Yes" />
  &nbsp;&nbsp; Type 2
  <input type="checkbox" name="Type 2" value="Yes" />
  &nbsp;
<p>&nbsp; Type 3
  <input type="checkbox" name="Type 3" value="Yes" />
  &nbsp;&nbsp; Type 4
  <input type="checkbox" name="Type 4" value="Yes" />

  <br />
  <br />
</div>
```

Comment: Great question TipTop, I just added it. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: There are 9 division boxes in total, 6 need to appear next to each other in the webpage, but they appear vertically, each one under the one before it. On Dreamweaver's browser it appears how it should, just not when it is uploaded to the site. I think it has something to do with the CSS I just can't figure out what.

Comment: It's probably something really basic haha

Comment: Thanks very much. I did try removing all the <p> tags to see if it had an effect, but my problem still remains. It was worth a shot though, and I have never heard of Jsfiddle it looks like a good tool.

Comment: NEVER NEVER trust Dreamweaver preview - USE A REAL BROWSER for preview. It's a trap.

Comment: What do you mean by 'trap'?

Comment: Thanks I will try that as well, I managed to work around the issue by starting again with a template from http://bradfrost.github.io/this-is-responsive/patterns.html#

Answer (score 0):

I tried using http://bradfrost.github.io/this-is-responsive/patterns.html# as a basic template and it ended up working how I wanted it to. It did require starting again and copying and pasting only the relevant code.

TRY THIS: http://bradfrost.github.io/this-is-responsive/patterns.html#